# TListView - How to rearrange items on resize

Tags: delphi, listview

I have a **TListView** that displays small thumbnails `(ViewStyle:=vsIcon)`.
At run time I assign images to to items:

```
  for i := 0 to Total - 1 DO
   with ListView.Items.Add DO
     begin
      Caption := 'Item ' + IntToStr(i);
      ImageIndex := i;
     end;
```

At start up the form is not very wide and the thumbnails are shown on only 3 columns. Unfortunately, If I resize the form (and the **ListView**) the column count will remain 3 and in the right side I will have a lot of white space.

This won't work also:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ListView.IconOptions.AutoArrange := TRUE;
end;
```

How do I rearrange the items to fill the empty space?
There is any property like AutoArrange?

---

Update:
I deleted the old control and I put a new one on the form.
Now `ListView.IconOptions.AutoArrange` works. There was something (some settings I made) in the previous control that prevented AutoArrange from working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There *is* a property like `AutoArrange`. It belongs to the [`IconOptions`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.IconOptions) property instead of directly to the list view.

```
ListView1.IconOptions.AutoArrange := True;
```

To make a one-time arrangement of the icons, you can call `ListView_Arrange` instead.